# How to query concat, group_concat, group by in MySQL for multiple subquery

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

I have database structure and data:

```
id | total | type | value_1 | value_2
1  |   9   |   1  |    10   |    20
2  |   9   |   1  |    21   |    30
3  |   10  |   1  |    31   |    40
4  |   9   |   2  |    41   |    50
5  |   9   |   2  |    51   |    60
6  |   8   |   2  |    61   |    70
```

Please help me how to query result like this?

```
type ||  total  ||    id   ||       value
1    ||   9|10  ||  1,2|3  ||  10-20,21-30|31-40
2    ||   9|8   ||  4,5|6  ||  41-50,51-60|61-70
```

Comment: At the moment, I can only query group by total, and I got a bit of difficulty when trying to group by type

SELECT
 total,
 GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR '|') AS id,
 GROUP_CONCAT(
  CONCAT_WS(
   '-',
   value_1,
   value_2
  ) SEPARATOR '|'
 ) AS value
FROM
 table
GROUP BY
 total

Answer (score 0):

This should work once you change the table name. The trick is to build it up in stages. First, combine `value_1` and `value_2`, then group by total and type using `,` as a separator, then finally, group by type using `|`.

```
select type,
group_concat(distinct total separator '|') as total, 
group_concat(distinct id separator '|') as id, 
group_concat(distinct vals separator '|') as vals 
from ( select type, 
    group_concat(distinct total separator ',') as total, 
    group_concat(distinct id separator ',') as id, 
    group_concat(distinct vals separator ',') as vals,
    count(id) as count 
    from (select id, total, type, concat(value_1,'-',value_2) as vals from tbl) as a
    group by total, type order by count desc) as b
group by type;
```

I replicated your table so I could test it out

```
mysql> select * from tbl;
+------+-------+------+---------+---------+
| id   | total | type | value_1 | value_2 |
+------+-------+------+---------+---------+
|    1 |     9 |    1 |      10 |      20 |
|    2 |     9 |    1 |      21 |      30 |
|    3 |    10 |    1 |      31 |      40 |
|    4 |     9 |    2 |      41 |      50 |
|    5 |     9 |    2 |      51 |      60 |
|    6 |     8 |    2 |      61 |      70 |
+------+-------+------+---------+---------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is the result.

```
mysql> select type,
-> group_concat(distinct total separator '|') as total, 
-> group_concat(distinct id separator '|') as id, 
-> group_concat(distinct vals separator '|') as vals 
-> from ( select type, 
-> group_concat(distinct total separator ',') as total, 
-> group_concat(distinct id separator ',') as id, 
-> group_concat(distinct vals separator ',') as vals,
-> count(id) as count 
-> from (select id, total, type, concat(value_1,'-',value_2) as vals from tbl) as a
-> group by total, type order by count desc) as b
-> group by type;
+------+-------+-------+-------------------+
| type | total | id    | vals              |
+------+-------+-------+-------------------+
|    1 | 9|10  | 1,2|3 | 10-20,21-30|31-40 |
|    2 | 9|8   | 4,5|6 | 41-50,51-60|61-70 |
+------+-------+-------+-------------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: type 1 -> total (9 and 10 => 9|10) -> total 9 has id 1 and 2, total 10 has id 3 --> 1,2|3

type 2 -> total (9 and 8 => 9|8) -> total 9 has id 4 and 5, total has id 6 => 4,5|6

Please help me check your query string.

Comment: What are the rules for using a `|` vs using a `,`?

Comment: My desired results: (please see on #1 for beauty-format)

type ||  total  ||    id   ||       value
1    ||   9|10  ||  1,2|3  ||  10-20,21-30|31-40
2    ||   9|8   ||  4,5|6  ||  41-50,51-60|61-70

Comment: I taking this for type = 1

When see on the result, we see total 9 has two id: 1 and 2, total 10 has one id: 3

Your query result, we can not identify total 9 has id 1 or 2 or 3 v.v...

Comment: | for diferrent total value
, for same total value

Comment: I recognize that the order is backwards from what you put above, but the edit should get you to what you want.

Comment: Ok thanks, I trying of editing your query string. If I don't success, please help me later.

Comment: I believe that the only difference in my result and what you have is that the total for type 2 is in reverse order (id and vals as well). But if you look at what you have you have an ascending pair and a descending pair in the same column. So unless there is another rule to add, this may be as close as you will get.

Comment: Assuming you were interested in ordering them by how many ids were associated with the total, I'm not getting what you have above.